# Decidability Proof of $A_{Cfg}$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, context-free, pushdown-automata

I am a beginner to complexity theory and I came up with the following proof of decidability of

$A_{Cfg}$ = {$<G,w>|G$ is a context free grammar that generates string $w$}

The Turing machine which decides $A_{Cfg}$ first converts the given grammar into a non-deterministic push down automata NPDA. And then we do an **epsilon closure** to this NPDA to get a non-determinstic push down automata without any $\epsilon$ moves N.

Now we can directly simulate N on a turing machine. Since we can be sure that **N halts**, our turing machine also halts deciding $A_{Cfg}$.

Is there any mistake in this proof because Sipser uses Chomsky normal form for this and I think this is simpler?

Comment: How precisely are you taking the epsilon closure of the NPDA?

Comment: There could be several ways of proving every single theorem. Textbooks don't enumerate all of them.

Comment: @templatetypedef I will take it in the same way as for a normal NFA with epsilon moves : Compute the epsilon closure for a node and to this node, add all the transitions (including the symbol to push on stack) from any node in the closure to any other node in the automaton. Do this for all the nodes in the automaton.

Comment: What if there's a cycle of epsilon transitions that pushes a nonzero number of symbols onto the stack? You could potentially push as many copies of the pushed symbols onto the stack as you'd like. (This is one of the reasons why it's hard to determinize PDAs; my understanding is that there is no canonical epsilon-free form for PDAs).

Comment: @templatetypedef Thanks a lot!. That answers my question.